Почему стили с одинаковыми идентифкаторами из разных файлов переплетаются?
Почему стили с одинаковыми индексами но в разных файлах переплетаются
Например:
У нас есть следующая структура: папка components и в ней ещё две папки например head и body
и почему если в этих папках создать по папке со стилями styles.css и в этих папках создать стиль с интексом допустим .background  и призначить этот стиль например в компоненте, который находится в head, стили можно будет менять из папки со стилями, которая находится в папке body
очень странно, ранее с такой проблемой не встречался
Структура: https://i.sstatic.net/nSySERKP.png
test1.tsx:
import React from 'react'
import './styles1.css'
const test1 = () => {
  return (
    <div className='test'>
      test
    </div>
  )
}

export default test1


style1.css:
.test {
   background-color: red; 
}

и выходит так, что если я создам точно такой же индекс (test) в style2.css то соответсвенно можно будет менять test стиль из style1.css в style2.css

Приведите пример кодом

может так немного понятнее

Потому что, ну, одинаковые идентификаторы. В CSS нету никакого разделения по пространствам имён, областям видимости или чему-то подобному, всё общее

понятно, странно почему я раньше не парился по этому поводу (я давно не использовал стили css, scss и тд...), спасибо

@andreymal, в css modules, которые в реакте используются - есть. Но тут они просто не используются :)

какой сборщик используется? используется ли реакт? только ли реакт используется?

использую vite (rollup), только react

чтобы не пересекались используй css-modules
